# Rails 4 Paypal REST API integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, model

I've installed the gem and [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK) says to do. I've made a separate model for [creating a payment](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK#create-payment) part of the instructions but I'm not sure **how to call making a payment from within my orders controller**. Also I need to be able to set the Payment attributes dynamically from my order but I've tried a couple of different ways of trying to achieve this with no luck.

I've tried calling Payments.pay in my orders controller and I get an error saying the method pay doesn't exist but I do have the method in the Payments class. The partial code for the Payments class is:

```
class Payments < PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment

def pay
  @payment = Payment.new({
      :intent => "sale",
      :payer => {
        :payment_method => "credit_card",
        :funding_instruments => [{
           :credit_card => {
           :type => "visa",
           :number => "4567516310777851",
           :expire_month => "11",
           :expire_year => "2018",
           :cvv2 => "874",
           :first_name => order.first_name,  # Need to do something similar to this but doesn't work 
           # etc...
    end
end
```

To sum up what I need help with is how can I make a call to this method in another controller or model so the payment can be processed and also how can i set the fields dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

I see a few potential issues.

First of all, you're using the method as a class method, so it should be

def self.pay
end

in order for Payments.pay to work. The way you define it currently is as an instance method.

If you wanted to call this method in a controller and pass in field dynamically you'd need to edit the pay function to accept arguments.  And possible import this class in to the controller.

You might just want to create a before_action :pay callback in one of your controllers and define the method / call Paypal SDK like below.  This would allow you to grab params and use them in the method (although I don't think you should be handling CC numbers, Paypal will probably handle this and pass you some sort of token that you then use).  Also look out for the way Paypal namespaces the library, it can be tricky when you're calling Paypal::SDK::REST etc.

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :pay

  def create
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end 

  private

  def pay
    @payment = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payment.new({
      :intent => "sale",
      :payer => {
        :payment_method => "credit_card",
        :funding_instruments => [{
           :credit_card => {
           :type => "visa",
           :number => params[:number],
           :expire_month => params[:month],
           :expire_year => params[:year],
           :cvv2 => params[:cvv],
           :first_name => @order.first_name,  # Need to do something similar to this but doesn't work 
           # etc...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I will try to work with this once I get home from work later on and go through some of the stuff you've said, thanks!